# Do any functions fire when going "back" to a view with a UINavigation

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I know its probably a really simple thing, but I need to reload some data if some changes have been made from a subview and then the master view is returned to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at implementing

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
```

or

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
```

But note there can be a problem that needs to be taken care of for UINavigationControllers [Link>>](http://davidebenini.it/2009/01/03/viewwillappear-not-being-called-inside-a-uinavigationcontroller/)